# How to compose given add, sub, mult, div functions to map an integer M to N?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

Given six integers ($M$, $N$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$), is it possible to create a function $H$ such that $H(M) = N$, with the restriction that $H$ is a composition of the following four functions (which may be applied zero or more times, and may be applied in any order):

$$A(x) = x + a\qquad B(x) = x - b\qquad C(x) = x\cdot c\qquad D(x) =\frac{x}{d}$$

These functions correspond with add, subtract, multiply, divide.

For example, suppose $M = 21$, $N = 32$, $a = 10$, $b = 4$, $c = 2$, $d = 3$.

The following is a solution:

$$ H = C\ \circ \ D\ \circ\ B\ \circ\ A\ \circ\ C $$

$$H(21) = \left(\frac{((21 \cdot  2) + 10) - 4}{3}\right) \cdot  2  = 32$$

---

Here is what I have considered so far.

If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, we can make $H$ from just add and subtract operations. When that isn't the case, such as in the example above, where the $\gcd(a,b) = 2$, we are in a different situation. Above, using just add and/or subtract, we can arrive at all odd numbers.

In general, if $\gcd(a,b) = g$, then we can make an $H$ such that $H(M) = M + gk$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. In other words, one can map $M$ to any integer $j$ such that $M\equiv j \pmod{g}$. In the above example, we could use multiply by 2 in order to expand to an even number, and then use adds or subtracts in order to arrive at any even integer.

At this point I got stuck. I am not sure how to apply multiply and divide to equivalence classes modulo $g$. (In particular the divide operation, since it can take integer dividends into non-integral quotients). Lastly, although I think this approach could prove the existence of such an $H$, I am unsure how to extract the ordering of function compositions to build it.

Later on, I will be interested in a method for finding the $H$ with the least number of function transpositions.

---

This question was inspired by a question posted on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784861/applying-a-sequence-of-operations-from-n-to-obtain-the-value-m). I am interested in the case where division is applied normally, i.e. 3 / 2 = 1.5 and not integer division such as in C++ (decimals truncated toward zero). This means $H$ may be a mapping from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to writing `$a\equiv b \bmod m$` because I prefer to write the modulus without the parentheses; as I've just edited, if you want parentheses, you should use `\pmod` instead of `\bmod` (they mean the same thing, some people write it differently, is all). You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Thanks, the formatting is a lot nicer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent question is for what $M$, $N$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ does the equation $Mc^m + k\cdot \gcd(a,b) = Nd^n$ have a solution. Any composition of $A, B, C, D$ can be transformed into this form. The above equation can also be written as $Mc^m \equiv Nd^n \pmod{\gcd(a,b)}$. Even when the answer isn't immediately apparent, because $c^m$ and $d^n$ attain only finitely many values $\pmod{\gcd(a, b)}$, a solution can be found by brute force.